# How Ethereum take fees in broadcast?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, transactions, tokens

Can I broadcast someone else signed transaction and use fee from my address? if yes then how?

Let me elaborate my Question Suppose person A want to transfer some ERC tokens to person B. But person A got zero ether in his account. so person A will sign the transaction and give it to person C and person C will broadcast the transaction. So in this case which account fee will deduct from person A's or from person C's.
if it will try to take from person A i want something like it will take fee from person C's account.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

> How Ethereum take fees in broadcast?

It doesn't. Broadcasting is free. Your assumption cannot be done.

Comment: I am new to Ethereum just trying to understand this transaction fees. There is GitHub repo. which i can not properly understand but in demo it is using its own account to pay for transaction fee. for your reference : https://github.com/opengsn/gsn

Comment: Gotcha. OpenGSN is a bit different as it is not part of core Ethereum, but a separate project where GSN members can broadcast your transaction for a fee. I do not know how it works though - because it is very new and little uesd.

Comment: But it does not work with standard wallets and Dapps, you need to build specific support for it.

Answer (score 0):

The ERC20 token standard requires an approve function to allow another address to spend tokens on behalf of the actual owner.
It means that account C can authorizes account A to use a certain amount of C's token .

-